# Is it possible to integrate app engine and firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to create a web app that is hosted using Google App Engine hosts and has multiple API endpoints. I have a Flask app for running for all the valid endpoints. The website is hosted successfully and it renders basic HTML. The problem is whenever I try getting data from my Firebase real-time database for that specific endpoint, I get an error 500 Internal server error. This is how I am trying to connect to the Firebase database.

```
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'databaseURL': f'https://{PROJECT_ID}-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com'
    }}
```

Whenever I try running the same app locally, on a local host, I can successfully add it to the database, suggesting the Firebase admin is set up correctly and all the keys are correct. I have added my website URL as an authorized domain but this is still now working. I wanted to ask if this is possible and if it is then what would be the best course of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify credentials or the URL in `initialize_app()`, per [the documentation for the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#python_1):

```py
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
```

> Once it is initialized, you can use the Admin SDK to accomplish the following types of tasks:
>
> - Implement custom authentication
> - Manage your Firebase Authentication users
> - **Read and write data from the Realtime Database**
> - Send Firebase Cloud Messaging messages

The default service account for AppEngine should already have [the necessary permissions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/access-control#apps):

> Every call to a Cloud service needs to be authenticated and authorized, including calls from an App Engine app to other Cloud services such as Cloud Storage.
>
> **By default, calls from your App Engine app to services in the same project are authorized.**

If the service account is not authorized then you can grant `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` access to Firebase Realtime Database  by [assigning in IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) [the pre-defined role `roles/firebase.admin`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-all-products).